# Collision when bounds of a view are changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit-dynamics

I am working with UIDynamicAnimator, UICollisionBehavior and several moving UIImageView.
It looks like this when everything is working fine. Pictures are moving on the screen without superposition. [image: Moving views with good collision]

But after I changed the bounds of some views, the collision doesn't update as it should and it gives me this: [image: Moving views after bounds animation]

The collision doesn't work anymore as expected: views became superposed.

I am updating the bounds with this code:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect newBounds = imageView.bounds;
                     newBounds.size.height = 500;
                     newBounds.size.width = 500;
                     imageView.bounds = newBounds;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [animator updateItemUsingCurrentState:imageView];
                 }];
```

`updateItemUsingCurrentState:` function doesn't seem to have effect on bounds changes... Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I succeed to do it by setting my animator variable to nil and declaring it and every linked animation behaviors again.**

If someone else has a better way to do it, I am still listening. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing all behaviors from the dynamic animator without deallocing it and re-adding them again:

```
        let behaviors = (self.dynamicAnimator.behaviors as NSArray).copy() as! [UIDynamicBehavior]
        self.dynamicAnimator.removeAllBehaviors()
        for behavior in behaviors {
            self.dynamicAnimator.addBehavior(behavior)
        }
```

Comment: I think I already tried that but didn't work out... I'll try again asap and give you feedback. Thanks.